# BackStackNavigation not working with NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, back-stack

According to some posts I found here I've implemented BackStackNavigation correctly but whenever I press Back button on any Fragment the app pops the current fragment, shows a flash of previous fragment and then exits. I couldn't solve this. Any help will be much appreciated. Am I doing it wrongly or is there some other thing?

The structure of my app is,

```
MainActivity -> NavigationDrawerFragment -> 1. RecyclerViewFragment -> TextViewFragment
                                            2. SlidingTabStrips.ViewPager (Fragment)
                                            3. Some Code (No fragments)
```

This is the `onBackPressed` overridden in `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack(backStack[TOP],
                FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        backStack[TOP] = null;
        TOP--;
        Log.e("BACK_STACK_COUNT_ON_POP",Integer
                .toString(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()));
        Log.e("TOP",Integer.toString(TOP));
    }
```

Now I replace the fragments in `NavigationDrawer` this way:

```
switch(position) {
            case 0: //Events
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                        EventsRecyclerViewFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                        .addToBackStack(EVENT_RV_FRAGMENT).commit();
                ++TOP;
                backStack[TOP] = EVENT_RV_FRAGMENT;
                break;

            case 1: //User
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                        UserFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                        .addToBackStack(USER_FRAGMENT).commit();
                ++TOP;
                backStack[TOP] = USER_FRAGMENT;
                break;

            case 2: //Logout
                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                if(prefs.getBoolean(KEY_LOGIN, false)) {
                    prefs.edit().remove(KEY_LOGIN).apply();
                    prefs.edit().remove(KEY_USERNAME).apply();
                    prefs.edit().remove(KEY_PASSWORD).apply();
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Customs.mToast(getBaseContext(), "Logged-out");
                }
                break;
        }
```

This is how i call TextViewFragment inside RecyclerViewFragment:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.container, eventFragment)
                            .addToBackStack(EVENT_FRAGMENT)
                            .commit();
                    ++TOP;
                    backStack[TOP] = EVENT_FRAGMENT;
```

**NavigationDrawer loaded `onCreate`:**

[image: Navigation Drawer]

**RecyclerViewFragment opened when I click Events from above:**

[image: RecyclerViewFragment]

**TextViewFragment opened when I click on one of the cards shown above:**

[image]

Comment: The backstack is automagically managed by Android. You don't have to do anything special to use it.  What you want to do?

Comment: I want to use backstack navigation ie. while I'm on an inner fragment like `TextViewFragment` and I press back button it should go to the previous fragment ie. `RecyclerViewFragment` but instead it exits the app.

Comment: Remove your overridden OnBackPressed, then it should work. As you are calling super.onBackPressed as the first action + popBackStack as the second, you are basically doing 2 backsteps, that's why your app gets closed I think. Remove all your own backstack handling and it will work.

Comment: On removing `onBackPressed` the app is directly exiting without even flashing the previous fragment

Comment: BTW I've used API 22 for compiling if that matters and running the app on API 21

Comment: Hey, I posted a complete working example for API lvl 21, I am currently installing API lvl 22...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution.

The original implementation of `onBackPressed()` in `ActionBarActivity.class` is..

`public void onBackPressed() { /* compiled code */ }`

So when we want to remove the top frament from stack we have to call `getFragmentManager().popBackStack()` in the `overridden onBackPressed()`.
And when the stack is empty call `super.onBackPressed()` which don't have anything so that the app will simply exit.

The overridden onBackPressed() should be such:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well yeah, about the problem with super.onBackPressed I wrote in one of my first comments 2 hours ago ... still, what you have done now is actually replicated the behaviour of super.onBackPressed, because the original implementation in activity does exactly what you do now with your own code. You'd actually override super.onBackPressed if you'd NOT want that behaviour.

Comment: @ElDuderino check my updated answer. It explains what happens exactly

Answer (score 0):

A very short working example... I didn't check out if it's an API problem, it works like this on lvl 21.

Add the first fragment with addToBackstack = false, add another with addToBackstack = true.

Activity (xml just contains relativelayout with id rlRoot)

```
public class FragActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.frag_activity);

    addFragment(new Frag1(), false, Frag1.TAG);

    addFragment(new Frag2(), true, Frag2.TAG);

}

private void addFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack, String tag) {

    FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    trans.replace(R.id.rlRoot, fragment, tag);
    if(addToBackStack) trans.addToBackStack(tag);
    trans.commit();

}
```

}

Fragments

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment {

public static final String TAG = Frag1.class.getSimpleName();

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(1));
    return tv;

}
```

}

```
public class Frag2 extends Fragment {

public static final String TAG = Frag1.class.getSimpleName();

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(2));
    return tv;

}
```

}

Comment: It works fine with simple fragment directly inside the MainActivity, but in my case the sequence is as I stated in the question and it doesn't work that way. I think maybe the NavigationDrawer is creating some problems

Comment: Ah I think now I get it. Fragment inside fragment ... did you check out ChildFragmentManager? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: I'm not using Fragment inside Fragment.. I'm replacing the present fragment with a new one. Sorry i wasn't clear about that before. So I guess I don't need to use `getChildFragmentManager()`

Comment: Well, if you don't do fragment in fragment .... then my code should be exactly what you need, replacing one fragment with another one. Maybe clarify your layout a bit more, for me it looks like you are loading  your NavigationDrawerFragment and then replace it with a RecyclerViewFragment. This is what my code does, replace one fragment with another. Make sure to addToBackstack only where you need it.

Comment: I added some images in the question, please check u'll get idea what i'm trying to do.